# JSON file not loading on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter, am currently stuck with my JSON file content not populating on my emulator. It shows no error, yet not displaying. If I include the content directly in my codeblock, it works fine. I can't spot the issue.

Below are my codes:

main.dart code

```
import 'package:emailapp/messagelist.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(EmailApp());

class EmailApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.green
      ),
      home: MessageList(title: 'Muss Mailer APP'),
    );
  }
}
```

messagelist.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MessageList extends StatefulWidget{

  final String title;

  const MessageList({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState()=>_MessageListState();
}

class _MessageListState extends State<MessageList>{
var messages=const [];

Future loadMessageList()  async{
  var content=await rootBundle.loadString('data/message.json');
  print(content);
  var collection=json.decode(content);

setState(() {
 messages=collection; 
});
}
void initstate() {
  loadMessageList();
  super.initState();
}
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),

    body: ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context,index)=>Divider(),

    itemCount: messages.length,

  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
    var message=messages[index];

    return ListTile(
      isThreeLine: true,
      leading: CircleAvatar( child: Text('AJ'),),
      title: Text(message['subject']),
      subtitle: Text(message['body'],maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),

      ) ;
  },
),


    );
  }

}
```

message.json

```
   [ {
        "subject":"My First Message",
  "body":"Hello Form the other side of life fellas.. and happy to meet you guys"

      },
      {
        "subject":"My Second Message",
  "body":"Hello Form the other side of life fellas.. and happy to meet you guys"

      },
      {
        "subject":"My Third Message",
  "body":"Hello Form the other side of life fellas.. and happy to meet you guys"

      },
      {
        "subject":"My Fourth Message",
  "body":"Hello Form the other side of life fellas.. and happy to meet you guys"

      },
      {
        "subject":"My Fifth Message",
  "body":"Hello Form the other side of life fellas.. and happy to meet you guys"

      },
      {
        "subject":"My Sixth Message",
  "body":"Hello Form the other side of life fellas.. and happy to meet you guys"

      }]
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
    - data/message.json
```

Comment: This question can be closed as "typo / unrepro", as the solution was/is a spelling error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a spelling mistake. It's not `initstate`. Its `initState` (**S** is capital).

```
void initState() {
  loadMessageList();
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: If the response fixed your issue. Please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making the following changes, to resolve some basic issues:

- add Override notation to `initState` and use `S` in `initState` name:
  as suggested by `@Crazy Lazy Cat`

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  loadMessageList();
  super.initState();
}
```

- remove the use of `setState` inside the `initState`, it is not recommended to set state of a widget which has not been built yet:

```dart
Future loadMessageList()  async{
  // everything else, as it is
  messages = collection; 
}
```

- remove `const []` from the messages, since it is replaced in the `initState` anyways.
- since the `loadMessageList` is async method you should use `FutureBuilder` for this purpose:

```dart
  FutureBuilder(
      future: loadMessageList,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? your_widget() : Container(),
  ),
```

`your_widget()` widget refers to the `ListView.separated` widget in the build method.

create `var messages = snapshot.data;` before defining the `ListView.separated` code.

for this to work you need to change the code in `loadMessageList`:

```dart
Future loadMessageList()  async {
  // everything else, as it is
  //messages = collection;
  return collection;
}
```

No need of global `messages` variable now.